# Random number isn't within contraints

Tags: java, arrays, histogram

So, I did re did the `e=(high-low)*x+low`, however, when I try to use it, it just returns an outOfBounds exception. When I didn't cast it into an int, it worked, however I ned it to return an integer, for the array to work.

```
public static int randomInt(int low, int high)
    {double e;
    double x=Math.random();
        e=(high-low)*x+low;
    return (int)e;}
```

Here is the method that calls the "randomInt" method

```
public static int[] randomIntArray(int n)//generates an array of random numbers based on an upper and lower bound
    {int[] a=new int[n];
    for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {a[i]=randomInt(-5,15);}//"-5&15 are the lower and upper bounds of the random number array
    return a;}
```

Comment: Why not use [java.Util.Random#nextInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-)?

Comment: This should not throw an OutOfBoundsException.

Comment: It didn't, turns out, the OutOfBoundsException was coming from a printing method I had to print this.

Answer (score 7):

x is between 0 and 1.

In order for e to be between `low` and `high`, you need:

```
e=(high-low)*x+low;
```

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/generating-random-integers-in-a-range-with-java)

```
public static int randInt(int min, int max) {

    Random rand = new Random();

    // nextInt is normally exclusive of the top value,
    // so add 1 to make it inclusive
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `return (int) (Math.random()*(high-low)+low);` as your function body instead.

Comment: When I use that, I just get an out of bounds exception